# How to Open a new JFrame window when JMenuItem is clicked

Tags: java, swing

Dear friend, I have a main application that contains a `Menu` and in each of this `Menu` there is a `JMenuItem`. I want when I click one of the `JMenuItem` I should be able to open a `new JFrame` that will do specific task. This `JFrame` should be in a different class that implements `ActionListener`, not in the same class that contains Main Method many example that I have seen in the internet and in http://stackoverflow.com does not give the solution in two different classes. When I try the same methods within the same class or as an inner class that implements `ActionListener` it works but not like I said 2 different classes. The reason I need it like that is because there is a lot of  `JMenuItems` in the `Menu` and each `JMenuItem` handles a great deal of process. If I am going to place everything in one file then it is not Object Oriented Programming any more and it is going to be a very very long file.  An example is shown below. However the bellow example did not work for me. Could some one point out what am I doing wrong. Thank in Advance.

Main class that implements main method.

```
public class SwendaEye{

    public static void main(String[]args){  
    FrameandComp frame = new FrameandComp();
    JFrame win;

    win = frame.mainFrame();
    JMenuBar bar;
    bar = new JMenuBar();
    win.setJMenuBar(bar); 

    JMenu swenda = new JMenu("SWENDAEYE");// adding Swenda menu to the bar.
    bar.add(swenda);

                 JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
                 swenda.add(open);
                 JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
                 swenda.add(exit);

    JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");// adding Tools menu to the bar.
    bar.add(tools);
                 JMenuItem convertIP = new JMenuItem("Convert IP Address");
                 tools.add(convertIP);
                 JMenuItem convertDomain = new JMenuItem("Convert Domain Name");
                 tools.add(convertDomain);
                 convertDomain.addActionListener(new Domain());

      win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the action Listener class separate from the above class

```
public class Domain implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if("Convert Domain Name".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

            JFrame awindow = new JFrame();
            awindow.setSize(200,400);
            awindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            awindow.setTitle("Convert");
            awindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);

        }

    }

}
```

In this example I am only demonstrating the Convert Domain Name `JMenuItem`.
and before you answer please do not tell me `JOptionPane` because I basically need to do a lot of thing in this window like table, image and many more. thank again.

Comment: Here we go again... Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `aWindow` visible.

Comment: Dude your the man, i knew it was something very silly, thanks a lot.